# Sharing link from own website to Linkedin app (iOS)

Tags: html, linkedin-api, share

I have a "share to Linkedin" button on my website. It's basically just a link and it works fine on desktop. This is the link:

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={my URL}

However, this doesn't work on mobile. If I try to share from my website on my phone (iOS), it opens the Linkedin app, but that's it. It doesn't open a post dialog or anything.

How can I make this work on mobile?

Answer (score 5):

Can you test with this url :

[https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?mini=true&url=${this.currentUrl}](https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?mini=true&url=$%7Bthis.currentUrl%7D)

```
const url = https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=${this.currentUrl}&title=${this.title}&source=${this.client.name}
const title = 'Linkedin'
const width = 600
const height = 400
let left = window.screen.width - width
let top = window.screen.height - height

top = top > 0 ? top / 2 : 0
left = left > 0 ? left / 2 : 0

window.open(url, title, `width=${width},height=${height},resizable=yes,left=${left},top=${top}`);
```

Comment: I realise that your "link" is actually more like helpful code. No idea how, but I think you should make that more obvious. Because people here might confuse this with a (not appreciated) link-only answer. Also, if you could add any explanation it would make the answer more "upvotable". But again, I could understand if you discovered and used this like "magic". (Nothing bad meant here, no cynicsim or anything, just to be clear.)